# Given sums of the first and last rows and the sums of all columns in a Nx2 matrix ,find the value of each cell in matrix (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm currently studying for interview exams (trying to get my first job).
I'm having a really hard time to find an algorithm for this question. I'd love to have some help:

Given sums of the first and last rows and an array with the sums of all columns in an Nx2 matrix, find the value of each cell in the matrix, where each cell is either 0 or 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not a question about programming. Its rather a puzzle. Solve it with pen and paper first, then writing the code should be trivial

Comment: either I miss something or the cases where there is a unique solution are rare. Do you need to find one solution or a unique one?

Comment: btw from my limited experience with interviews, I'd say that they want to see how you tackle the problem, they don't expect you to know the solution. The want to see that you can develop a solution not test if you can remember the solution

Comment: A naïve algorithm would be recursive, assuming there is a solution, with random choice and conditions checks. You iterate through all possible combination of the two cells of the nth column, and if none pass the rows sums checks (current sum above expected sum), you go back one column to test the n-1 column next combination. Otherwise, you move to n+1 with the first combination that passes on the nth column. This will only find one solution, if it exists

Comment: wait, are you sure the matrix is not 2xN (2 rows, N cols)?

Comment: I've written an answer and a discussion has started as a result. Can the question author shed some light on it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the matrix to be recreated is 2xN and not Nx2. Then you have every sum necessary to find an answer to the question.

A naïve algorithm would be recursive, with random choice and conditions checks. You iterate through all possible combination of the two cells of the nth column, and if none pass the rows sums checks (current sum above expected sum), you go back one column to test the n-1 column next combination. Otherwise, you move to n+1 with the first combination that passes on the nth column. This will only find one solution, if it exists

In pseudocode the recursive method would look like:

```
def find_combination_for_column(n):
  if n > max_n return 0
  for each x, y in possible_combination(n)
    if n == max_n and curr_sum_1 + x == expected_1 and curr_sum_2 + y == expected_2
      // result foud here, print and exit
      print(x, y)
      return 1
    if curr_sum_1 + x > expected_1 or curr_sum_2 + y > expected_2
      // go back to previous column
      return 0
    if find_combination_for_column(n + 1)
      // result already found, all that's left is to print this column's parameters and continue exiting
      print(x, y)
      return 1
    // else go to next combination
```

**Edit**

Did not see that the only possible values where 0 and 1. This naive approach should still work though, but you will be able to skip columns for which the sum is 0 or 2 as only one combination is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have N rows and 2 columns, and the sum for each row and column.

There is no need of backtracking, finding a solution is doable in linear time (there are actually usually more than 1 solution). If there is a solution, you will find it. Otherwise, you can determine it.

In pseudo code :

```
rows_with_choice = []
sum_so_far = 0
# Fill all rows for which there is no choice
for i in range(N):
  # If the sum is 0, each element is 0. If the sum is 2, they are both 1.
  if sum_row(i) in [0; 2] : 
    M[i][0] = sum_row(i) / 2
    M[i][1] = sum_row(i) / 2
    sum_so_far += sum_row(i)
  else:
    rows_with_choice.append(i)   # These are the indices of the rows that contain either (0; 1) or (1; 0)
already_in_each_col = sum_so_far / 2  # Each column already has that number of 1s.
if already_in_each_col > min(sum_col):
  print('No solution exists')
  return
if len(rows_with_choice) + sum_so_far != sum_col[0] + sum_col[1]:
  print('No solution exists')
  return
# Among the rows that have a choice, fill the correct amount as (1; 0) and the rest as (0; 1)
for j in range(sum_col(0) - already_in_each_col):
  i = rows_with_choice[j]
  M[i][0] = 1
  M[i][1] = 0
for j in range(sum_col(1) - already_in_each_col):
  i = rows_with_choice[j + sum_col(0) - already_in_each_col] 
  M[i][0] = 0
  M[i][1] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is not answer possible: let me demonstrate this with the following example: find a 4x4 matrix where every cell value is 0 or 1, and the sum of every row and every column equals 2. There are following solutions:

```
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1

0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0

1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1

0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0

1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1

... (there are lots and lots of solutions)
```

I believe the real question of this interview is: are you able to determine that a question is unsolvable?

Comment: While it is still true that there may be a lot of solutions with this setting, he specified that the matrix is Nx2.

Comment: N rows and 2 columns. Ok, but this still does not make the situation solvable.

Comment: Your point stays correct that there may be no or multiple solutions. But you can still find one, or several, solutions, in the cases where they exist; or say that no solution exists in the other case.

Comment: @gdelab: I do understand your point, but I would be the interviewer asking that question and the person comes up with an algorithm (after quite some time), I would reply "Did you even consider that this question might be unsolvable?" and I would flunk the candidate for not detecting that. If, however, the candidate would reply "Sir, you're asking me a question which might not even have a solution.", I'll be happy to modify the question into a solvable one, and I would congratulate the candidate for this sharpness of mind.

Comment: You call sharpness of mind what all participants here assumed. Your answer is that there is "no possible answer" but you come up with tons of solutions that answer the problem as it is. I actually think the point of this kind of question is to show the interviewer problem solving AND coding skills. I'm sure pointing out that there might be multiple solutions is very good, but it will be a bonus at best.